# user authentication methods for apple watch app

Tags: ipad, session, authentication, apple-watch, ios-app-extension

I have an iPad and iPhone application,which runs on user session and requires login and session to be maintained throughout application life cycle. Now I want to create Apple watch app for same app. What are the best ways to do login and maintain session on Apple watch. User session expires if app is idle for more than 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Look at shared keychain access within the app group. You should be able to pass your auth token to WatchKit that way.

Comment: thanks, for reply. I will try out . For now not working on it.

Comment: shared keychain is not available since WatchOS 2 if I am correct. Is there any other ways to achieve something similar in a secured way?